# React MUI Buttons are failing because element type is not defined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `MUI Buttons` for my project and it always throws this error when I render a button, it was working fine and suddenly started throwing it:

```
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Debugging it I saw that for some reason the button elements created by MUI do not have a specific property that React uses to check the type of the element that it needs to load, specifically `$$typeof`.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    useMutation,
    useQueryClient
} from 'react-query';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import Archive from '@mui/icons-material/Archive';
import Edit from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import Unarchive from '@mui/icons-material/Unarchive';
import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';


const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
    <Grid container item xs={8} justifyContent="flex-end" alignItems="center">
         <IconButton onClick={() => setEditDialogOpen(true)} aria-label="edit">
             <Edit />
         </IconButton>
    </Grid>
    );
}
```

It fails when react tries to figure out the type of the component, because for some reason the type doesn't have a property `$$typeof` instead it only has an empty object property called `default`.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, turns out I had my `package.json` using `"type": "module"` when I removed that it worked as expected.

There appears to be an issue if I used type "module" with emotionjs. I needed to modify a couple of my files to accomodate for the change like my `jest.config.js` and my `.eslintrc.js`.